# how can i keep the class table in new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to show a table with id = "x_t" in div with id="x" in new window:

```
function showOrHideTable(id) {
       var div = document.getElementById(id);
       var popup = window.open("about:blank");
       popup.document.open();
       popup.document.write('<html><head></head>' + div.innerHTML + '</html>');
   popup.document.getElementById(id + '_t').style.display = "block";
   popup.document.getElementById(id + '_t').setAttribute("class","table sortable");
       popup.document.close();
}
```

But setting atribute class "table sortable" in the new window, does not take efect...
in the parent windows, it shows perfect with this class, but not in new window.
The table appears as text plain and its bad..

How can I keep the class of table in the new window?
thank you and excuse my english

EDIT:
sortable is a js that makes table sortable by columns
table is a css that its loaded by:

lift:surround with="default" at="content">

Comment: You'll also need to define those classes in the new window's document. i.e. include the stylesheets defining those as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the class attribute isn't sufficient. You'll need to define those classes in the new window's document. i.e. include the stylesheets defining those as well. Suppose the CSS classes `table` and `sortable` are defined in `styles.css`, you'll need to do the following:

```
function showOrHideTable(id) {
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    var popup = window.open("about:blank");
    popup.document.open();
    popup.document.write('<html><head>'++
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">'+ // include the stylesheet
        '</head>' + div.innerHTML + '</html>');
    popup.document.getElementById(id + '_t').style.display = "block";
    popup.document.getElementById(id + '_t').setAttribute("class","table sortable");
    popup.document.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.

In fact, sortable is a js script, wich is loaded in the main page as:
<script src="sorttable.js"></script>

table is in css. But project is a liftweb, all pages init by:

lift:surround with="default" at="content">

And table class is automatically loaded...

Can I init the new page with lift:surround, and class table will load?